# Exporting shared library symbols in a crossplatform way?

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, visual-c++, dllexport

Is there a cross platform way to selectively export certain functions and structs from a C project which builds a shared library?

I want to do in a way that does not require a specific build system (the visibility should be defined in the code, eg as a macro), and in a way which both GCC and MSVC can understand.

Thank you.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164827/explicitly-exporting-shared-library-functions-in-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly no, of course, because the toolchains aren't the same.

But people do this.  The complexities are that in windows, you need to
specifically tag the declarations of functions you want exported from
a DLL with `__declspec(dllexport)` in the location in the library where
the function is **defined** and `__declspec(dllimport)` in the locations
in client code where the funciton is **referenced**.  Because standard
C practice has only one declaration in a single header file, this
means that you generally need to do some macro work to have a single
prefix that works in both locations.  It seems like every project
picks its own standard for this.

On the Unix side, you don't need to tag exports at all, which is nice.
This is because **every** non-static function is exported by default,
which is not so nice.  Often you can get away with this as long as
your non-public/non-static symbols have sane prefixes, which is what
most projects seem to do.  If you need finer control over your
exported symbols, you can use a Solaris-style "mapfile" with the GNU
linker's --version-script (-M under solaris) argument to define explicitly which symbols should appear
in the external namespace.

There are a few more gotchas between the platforms, like the way the
per-library global namespace works and the handling of
startup/shutdown code.  Basically, it's a rats nest that can't be
sanely explained in a post this short, but as long as you're careful
that your library contains simple functions and your namespace doesn't
pollute, you shouldn't have much trouble.  Look to some of the more
popular cross-platform shared libraries (e.g. Qt, Glib/Gtk+, anything
distributed with msys, etc...) for guidance.