# Explicitly exporting shared library functions in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

Is there a Linux equivalent of `__declspec(dllexport)` notation for explicitly exporting a function from a shared library? For some reason with the toolchain I'm using, functions that aren't class members don't appear in the resulting shared library file.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

And there is no equivalent of `__declspec(dllimport)` to my knowledge.

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    //  Microsoft 
    #define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #define IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    //  GCC
    #define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
    #define IMPORT
#else
    //  do nothing and hope for the best?
    #define EXPORT
    #define IMPORT
    #pragma warning Unknown dynamic link import/export semantics.
#endif
```

Typical usage is to define a symbol like `MY_LIB_PUBLIC` conditionally define it as either `EXPORT` or `IMPORT`, based on if the library is currently being compiled or not:

```
#if MY_LIB_COMPILING
#   define MY_LIB_PUBLIC EXPORT
#else
#   define MY_LIB_PUBLIC IMPORT
#endif
```

To use this, you mark your functions and classes like this:

```
MY_LIB_PUBLIC void foo();

class MY_LIB_PUBLIC some_type
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: A note about where to place the macro would be nice for future readers.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r Place the macro anywhere before you annotate EXPORT/IMPORT on anything. Most projects will have a specific place in some header where all of their global macros are defined.

Comment: @DanBechard I guess this was related to the position of the macro when using it on a function or class. There are some examples in the [GCC Wiki post](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility); rule of thumb: Use it before the return type of a function, and before a class name, e.g. `EXPORT void FunctionName()` and `class EXPORT ClassName`.

Comment: Thanks @janw! For some reason, I never put together that was what was being looked for here. Added usage guidance to the answer.