Java FFM, how to link a java object with a C struct?
I'd like to know how I can "link" a C struct to an object in Java with the FFM library.
I have a game in Java, and I'd ultimately like to allow users to create Luau scripts to interface with my game through an API. What I'm looking for is a way to send a "Player" object into C (to inevitably reach Lua), such that any changes made to the player through Java are immediately reflected in C (Lua as well), and any changes made in C/Lua are immediately reflected in Java where the core game logic is running.
I'd like for the player to remain accessible as long as it hasn't been explicitly freed
I can't really find any info on this topic, one potential solution I've thought of is to map a function for each operation I want to allow in C which calls a Java function and sets the player fields in java then maps it back to C again

If you want your changes to be applied immediately, you can write a class with getters and setters that access the MemorySegment.

Basics
Note the java.lang.foreign API documentation is quite good. I recommend reading it fully to get a good grasp on how to use it. Don't just read the linked package documentation; also read the documentation of the various types and their methods. You may want to familiarize yourself with the java.lang.invoke API as well.
That said, the Foreign Function & Memory (FFM) API provides the StructLayout interface for interacting with native structs. Make sure your StructLayout matches the memory layout of the native struct exactly. This includes any padding, as well as using the correct byte alignment and byte order.
For a simple example, if you have the following C struct:
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct Point {
    int32_t x;
    int32_t y;
} Point;

Then you would want to create a StructLayout like so:
StructLayout pointLayout = MemoryLayout.structLayout(
    ValueLayout.JAVA_INT.withName("x"),
    ValueLayout.JAVA_INT.withName("y"),
).withName("Point");

The MemoryLayout#structLayout(MemoryLayout...) takes a series of MemoryLayout. This means you can create an arbitrarily complex struct layout, including nested structs. Note calling withName is not actually necessary, but it can help when debugging problems. It can also make some FFM code more readable, such as when acquiring a VarHandle to a region of memory.
Once you have the StructLayout you can use a SegmentAllocator to allocate native memory for the struct from Java. This will give you a MemorySegment.
// 'Arena' is a subtype of 'SegmentAllocator'
try (Arena arena = Arena.ofConfined()) {
  MemorySegment pointSegment = arena.allocate(pointLayout);
  // use 'pointSegment'...

} // 'arena' is closed, releasing any memory it allocated

You can call the appropriate get and set methods of MemorySegment with the appropriate arguments to get and set the values of the struct's data members. You would pass this MemorySegment to any downcall MethodHandle (created via a Linker) that invokes a native function which accepts a Point struct. Similarly, if any such downcall MethodHandle invokes a native function that returns a Point struct then you'll receive a MemorySegment.
When interacting with native functions, be cognizant of whether or not you're dealing with pointers. That changes how you both create and invoke the downcall MethodHandle. See Linker#downcallHandle(FunctionDescriptor,Option...) for more information.

Wrapper Java Class
Directly using a StructLayout and a MemorySegment at all times is not ideal. You can make it more intuitive by creating a wrapper class that wraps the MemorySegment and exposes getters and setters. This will make interacting with the native struct look just like interacting with a regular Java object. You can also use MemoryLayout#varHandle(PathElement...) to make implementing the getters and setters easier.
package com.example;

import static java.lang.foreign.MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement;
import static java.lang.foreign.MemoryLayout.structLayout;
import static java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout.JAVA_INT;

import java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment;
import java.lang.foreign.SegmentAllocator;
import java.lang.foreign.StructLayout;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.VarHandle;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class Point {

  private final MemorySegment segment;

  // allocates new memory for a new Point struct (0, 0)
  public Point(SegmentAllocator allocator) {
    this(allocator, 0, 0);
  }

  // allocates new memory for a new Point struct (x, y)
  public Point(SegmentAllocator allocator, int x, int y) {
    this(allocator.allocate(LAYOUT));
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
  }

  // already allocated Point struct (e.g., from native code)
  public Point(MemorySegment segment) {
    if (segment.byteSize() != LAYOUT.byteSize())
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("segment's byte size does not match layout's");
    this.segment = segment;
  }

  // Allows passing Point to native functions
  public MemorySegment segment() {
    return segment; // may want to return read-only view?
  }

  public int getX() {
    return (int) X.get(segment);
  }

  public void setX(int x) {
    X.set(segment, x);
  }

  public int getY() {
    return (int) Y.get(segment);
  }

  public void setY(int y) {
    Y.set(segment, y);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this == obj || (obj instanceof Point other && segment.equals(other.segment));
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(Point.class, segment);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Point(x=" + getX() + ", y=" + getY() + ")";
  }

  /* *****************************************************************************
   *                                                                             *
   * FFM State                                                                   *
   *                                                                             *
   *******************************************************************************/

  public static final StructLayout LAYOUT;

  private static final VarHandle X;
  private static final VarHandle Y;

  static {
    LAYOUT = structLayout(JAVA_INT.withName("x"), JAVA_INT.withName("y")).withName("Point");

    var x = LAYOUT.varHandle(groupElement("x"));
    X = MethodHandles.insertCoordinates(x, 1, 0L); // bind offset argument to 0

    var y = LAYOUT.varHandle(groupElement("y"));
    Y = MethodHandles.insertCoordinates(y, 1, 0L); // bind offset argument to 0
  }
}

Also see my answer to How can I write an array-like datastructure in Java that takes longs as indices using modern unsafe APIs? for ideas on dealing with native arrays.

Executable Example
Here is an executable example demonstrating the use of FFM with a C struct. Specifically, it demonstrates:

Allocating the struct in native and using it in Java.

Allocating the struct in Java and using it in native.

Seeing modifications done in Java on the native side.

Seeing modifications done in native on the Java side.

Invoking native functions that either return or accept the struct.

How to handle the return value of a native function in Java when it's a pointer versus when it's not.


Native Code (C)
Here is the native shared library named nativepoint.
nativepoint.h
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    //  Microsoft 
    #define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #define IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    //  GCC
    #define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
    #define IMPORT
#else
    //  do nothing and hope for the best?
    #define EXPORT
    #define IMPORT
    #pragma warning Unknown dynamic link import/export semantics.
#endif
// Above taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2164853/6395627

#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct Point {
    int32_t x;
    int32_t y;
} Point;

EXPORT Point* newPoint(int x, int y);

EXPORT Point newPointByValue(int x, int y);

EXPORT void swapPoint(Point *const point);

EXPORT void printPoint(const Point *const point);

nativepoint.c
#include "nativepoint.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

Point* newPoint(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    Point *point = malloc(sizeof *point);
    point->x = x;
    point->y = y;
    return point;
}

Point newPointByValue(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    Point point = {x, y};
    return point;
}

void swapPoint(Point *const point) {
    const int32_t x = point->x;
    point->x = point->y;
    point->y = x;
}

void printPoint(const Point *const point) {
    printf("[NATIVE]: Point(x=%d, y=%d)\n", point->x, point->y);
    fflush(stdout); // stay "in sync" with Java logging
}

Java Code
Here is the Java code. The Point class is a wrapper around the native struct Point. The NativePointLib class is a wrapper around the native functions.
module-info.java
module com.example {}

Point.java
Same as from "Wrapper Java Class" section.
NativePointLib.java
package com.example;

import java.lang.foreign.Arena;
import java.lang.foreign.FunctionDescriptor;
import java.lang.foreign.Linker;
import java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment;
import java.lang.foreign.SegmentAllocator;
import java.lang.foreign.SymbolLookup;
import java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class NativePointLib {

  private NativePointLib() {}

  public static Point newPoint(Arena arena, int x, int y) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(arena, "arena");
    try {
      /*
       * The 'newPoint' native function returns a *pointer* to a Point struct. In other words, the
       * memory was already allocated off the stack. That's why a SegmentAllocator is not passed to
       * the MethodHandle (unlike 'newPointByValue' below). However, we are still responsible for
       * releasing the memory when appropriate. Generally, this will be done using one of the
       * following approaches:
       *
       *     1. Associating the memory with an Arena via MemorySegment::reinterpret. Then the
       *        memory will be released when the Arena is closed.
       *
       *     2. Manually invoking the 'free' native function. This will involve creating a downcall
       *        MethodHandle to said native function.
       *
       *     3. Invoking some library-specific native function that releases the memory. Again,
       *        this will involve creating a downcall MethodHandle to the native function.
       *
       * The first approach is used in this example.
       */
      var segment = (MemorySegment) NEW_POINT.invokeExact(x, y);
      segment = segment.reinterpret(arena, null); // associate memory with Arena
      return new Point(segment);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to invoke native 'newPoint'", t);
    }
  }

  public static Point newPointByValue(SegmentAllocator allocator, int x, int y) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(allocator, "allocator");
    try {
      /*
       * The 'newPointByValue' native function returns a Point struct *by value*. That is why a
       * SegmentAllocator is necessary; Java needs to know how to allocate the memory for the
       * returned value. The struct's memory will be released based on:
       * 
       *    1. If the SegmentAllocator is an Arena or backed by an Arena, then when the Arena is
       *       closed.
       * 
       *    2. If MemorySegment returned by the allocator is in the "automatic scope", then when
       *       it (and all other related objects) are garbage collected.
       * 
       * Note if the MemorySegment is in the global scope then it won't ever be released (until the
       * process terminates, of course).
       */
      var segment = (MemorySegment) NEW_POINT_BY_VALUE.invokeExact(allocator, x, y);
      return new Point(segment);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to invoke native 'newPointByValue'", t);
    }
  }

  public static void swapPoint(Point point) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(point, "point");
    try {
      SWAP_POINT.invokeExact(point.segment());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to invoke native 'swapPoint'", t);
    }
  }

  public static void printPoint(Point point) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(point, "point");
    try {
      PRINT_POINT.invokeExact(point.segment());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to invoke native 'printPoint'", t);
    }
  }

  /* *****************************************************************************
   *                                                                             *
   * FFM State                                                                   *
   *                                                                             *
   *******************************************************************************/

  private static final MethodHandle NEW_POINT;
  private static final MethodHandle NEW_POINT_BY_VALUE;
  private static final MethodHandle SWAP_POINT;
  private static final MethodHandle PRINT_POINT;

  static {
    var symbols = loadLibrary();
    var linker = Linker.nativeLinker();

    NEW_POINT = linkNewPoint(linker, symbols);
    NEW_POINT_BY_VALUE = linkNewPointByValue(linker, symbols);
    SWAP_POINT = linkSwapPoint(linker, symbols);
    PRINT_POINT = linkPrintPoint(linker, symbols);
  }

  private static MethodHandle linkNewPoint(Linker linker, SymbolLookup symbols) {
    var addr = getSymbol(symbols, "newPoint");
    // By using an ADDRESS layout with a target layout, the created MethodHandle will return a
    // MemorySegment of the correct size. Without the target layout you would have to call
    // 'reinterpret' on the segment.
    var desc = FunctionDescriptor.of(
        ValueLayout.ADDRESS.withTargetLayout(Point.LAYOUT),
        ValueLayout.JAVA_INT,
        ValueLayout.JAVA_INT);
    return linker.downcallHandle(addr, desc);
  }

  private static MethodHandle linkNewPointByValue(Linker linker, SymbolLookup symbols) {
    var addr = getSymbol(symbols, "newPointByValue");
    var desc = FunctionDescriptor.of(Point.LAYOUT, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT);
    // Since the return type is a GroupLayout, the created MethodHandle has an additional
    // argument of type SegmentAllocator. See the 'newPointByValue' method implementation above.
    return linker.downcallHandle(addr, desc);
  }

  private static MethodHandle linkSwapPoint(Linker linker, SymbolLookup symbols) {
    var addr = getSymbol(symbols, "swapPoint");
    // The target layout is not technically necessary here; you could just use ADDRESS
    var desc = FunctionDescriptor.ofVoid(ValueLayout.ADDRESS.withTargetLayout(Point.LAYOUT));
    return linker.downcallHandle(addr, desc);
  }

  private static MethodHandle linkPrintPoint(Linker linker, SymbolLookup symbols) {
    var addr = getSymbol(symbols, "printPoint");
    // The target layout is not technically necessary here; you could just use ADDRESS
    var desc = FunctionDescriptor.ofVoid(ValueLayout.ADDRESS.withTargetLayout(Point.LAYOUT));
    return linker.downcallHandle(addr, desc);
  }

  // convenience method to give better exception message if symbol could not be found
  private static MemorySegment getSymbol(SymbolLookup symbols, String name) {
    return symbols.find(name).orElseThrow(() -> {
      var msg = "'" + name + "' symbol not found in native library";
      return new IllegalStateException(msg);
    });
  }

  private static SymbolLookup loadLibrary() {
    /*
     * An algorithm that tries to load the library from various configuration options.
     *
     *     1. First, it checks if the 'nativepoint.path' system property has bee set to a non-blank
     *        value. If it has, then it loads the library from the specified file, throwing an
     *        exception if the load fails.
     *
     *     2. If the system property was not set, then it checks if the 'NATIVEPOINT_PATH'
     *        environment variable has been set to a non-blank value. If it has, then it loads the
     *        library form the specified file, throwing an exception if the load fails.
     *
     *     3. If neither the system property nor the environment variable have been set, then it
     *        tries to load the library by name via an OS-specific mechanism. See the documentation
     *        of SymbolLookup::libraryLookup(String,Arena) for more information.
     *
     *     4. If the library could not be loaded by name in step 3, then it attempts to load the
     *        library by name via 'System::loadLibrary(String)'. This searches the
     *        'java.library.path' system property.
     *
     * Note the way NativePointLib is designed does not give much control over when the library is
     * unloaded. If you want to be able to unload the library on demand, then you'll need to design
     * your API in such a way that it can accept a user-defined Arena to load the library into.
     */
    var location = System.getProperty("nativepoint.path");
    if (location == null || location.isBlank()) {
      location = System.getenv("NATIVEPOINT_PATH");
    }

    if (location != null && !location.isBlank()) {
      return SymbolLookup.libraryLookup(Path.of(location), Arena.global());
    }

    RuntimeException lookupByNameError;
    try {
      return SymbolLookup.libraryLookup("nativepoint", Arena.global());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalCallerException ex) {
      lookupByNameError = ex;
    }

    try {
      System.loadLibrary("nativepoint");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError error) {
      error.addSuppressed(lookupByNameError);
      var msg =
          """
          Could not load 'nativepoint' native library. Make sure to configure the runtime by:
             1. Setting the 'nativepoint.path' system property, or
             2. Setting the 'NATIVEPOINT_PATH' environment variable, or
             3. Placing the library in an OS-specific location where it can be found, or
             4. Placing the library on the 'java.library.path' system property.
          """;
      throw new IllegalStateException(msg, error);
    }
    return SymbolLookup.loaderLookup();
  }
}

Main.java
package com.example;

import java.lang.foreign.Arena;
import java.lang.foreign.SegmentAllocator;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("===== Point allocated in native via 'newPoint' =====");
    try (var arena = Arena.ofConfined()) {
      var point = NativePointLib.newPoint(arena, 10, 20);
      logPoint(point);
      demoSwapPoint(arena, point);
    }

    System.out.println("===== Point allocated in native via 'newPointByValue' =====");
    try (var arena = Arena.ofConfined()) {
      var point = NativePointLib.newPointByValue(arena, 15, 25);
      logPoint(point);
      demoSwapPoint(arena, point);
    }

    System.out.println("===== Point allocated in Java =====");
    try (var arena = Arena.ofConfined()) {
      var point = new Point(arena, 42, 117);
      logPoint(point);
      demoSwapPoint(arena, point);
    }
  }

  static void demoSwapPoint(SegmentAllocator allocator, Point point) {
    NativePointLib.swapPoint(point);
    log("After 'swapPoint'");
    logPoint(point);

    // now do swap in Java
    int x = point.getX();
    point.setX(point.getY());
    point.setY(x);

    log("After swap via 'setX' / 'setY' in Java");
    logPoint(point);
  }

  static void logPoint(Point point) {
    log(point.toString());
    NativePointLib.printPoint(point);
    System.out.println();
  }

  static void log(String msg) {
    System.out.printf("[JAVA  ]: %s%n", msg);
  }
}

Command
After compiling both the C library and the Java application:
java -Dnativepoint.path=<libpath> --enable-native-access=com.example -p <modpath> -m com.example/com.example.Main

Replace <libpath> with a path to the built shared library file. Replace <modpath> with a path pointing to your compiled Java application. See the code comment in the NativePointLib::loadLibrary() method for alternatives to setting the nativepoint.path system property.
Note modules are not necessary. You can remove the module-info descriptor. Just replace com.example with ALL-UNNAMED for --enable-native-access, set the class-path instead of the module-path, and launch with a class name or -jar instead of -m.
Output
===== Point allocated in native via 'newPoint' =====
[JAVA  ]: Point(x=10, y=20)
[NATIVE]: Point(x=10, y=20)

[JAVA  ]: After 'swapPoint'
[JAVA  ]: Point(x=20, y=10)
[NATIVE]: Point(x=20, y=10)

[JAVA  ]: After swap via 'setX' / 'setY' in Java
[JAVA  ]: Point(x=10, y=20)
[NATIVE]: Point(x=10, y=20)

===== Point allocated in native via 'newPointByValue' =====
[JAVA  ]: Point(x=15, y=25)
[NATIVE]: Point(x=15, y=25)

[JAVA  ]: After 'swapPoint'
[JAVA  ]: Point(x=25, y=15)
[NATIVE]: Point(x=25, y=15)

[JAVA  ]: After swap via 'setX' / 'setY' in Java
[JAVA  ]: Point(x=15, y=25)
[NATIVE]: Point(x=15, y=25)

===== Point allocated in Java =====
[JAVA  ]: Point(x=42, y=117)
[NATIVE]: Point(x=42, y=117)

[JAVA  ]: After 'swapPoint'
[JAVA  ]: Point(x=117, y=42)
[NATIVE]: Point(x=117, y=42)

[JAVA  ]: After swap via 'setX' / 'setY' in Java
[JAVA  ]: Point(x=42, y=117)
[NATIVE]: Point(x=42, y=117)


Love this, at the moment the classes I intend to pass to C aren't using VarHandle, for example I currently just have Point as two doubles in java.
Is it possible to do something like this without extensively modifying the class?

As far as I know, not with FFM. But you could with JNI.
